# C# sql data will lost after copy them

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm created a database(with VS wizard) which contains 2 columns : **Id , fData** ;; fData type is nvarchar(MAX).
and then i insert a file into with this command :

```
public void InsertToDB()
        {
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(barcodeEXE); //this is an exe file
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

            mytbl3TableAdapter.Insert(1, base64);
            mytbl3TableAdapter.Fill(mydb3DataSet.mytbl3);
            //FILE ADDED !
        }
```

now everythings is ok(file added into database with base64string format and we don't need to use those commands to insert file again) **problem** is here: i will copy the data from database to other folder with this commands :

```
 public void CopyFromDB()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = CnString;
            con.Open(); //start     

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT fData FROM [mytbl3] WHERE Id=1", con);

            using (SqlDataReader d = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                string base64;
                base64 = ((string)mydb3DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["fData"]);
                byte[] base64byte = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
                mytbl3TableAdapter.Update(mydb3DataSet.mytbl3);
                mytbl3TableAdapter.Fill(mydb3DataSet.mytbl3);

                SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog(); ofd.Filter = "exe file|*.exe";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(ofd.FileName, base64byte);


                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

                    d.Close();
                    //
                }
                d.Close();
            }

            //end
            con.Close();

        }
```

the file will copy successfully but data will remove from database!!

Comment: this is not copying data from DB, you are just fetching the data and nothing at all..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @reds No it works. i can send exe file to you. problem is data will remove from database. its like cut and past !

Comment: remove the two extra lines you have in copy from DB function:

    mytbl3TableAdapter.Update(mydb3DataSet.mytbl3);
     mytbl3TableAdapter.Fill(mydb3DataSet.mytbl3);

Comment: @Digvijay i do it but same problem ...

Comment: Please check the answer below!

Comment: @Digvijay i mean with your code even SaveFileDialog not open

Comment: that would be because there is no data in database!

Answer (score 0):

The CopyFromDB function looks to be not doing what you intend to:

```
public void CopyFromDB()
{
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = CnString;
        con.Open(); //start     

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT fData FROM [mytbl3] WHERE Id=1", con);

        using (SqlDataReader d = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (d.Read())
            {
                string base64;
                base64 = reader.GetString(d.GetOrdinal("fData"));
                byte[] base64byte = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

                SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog(); ofd.Filter = "exe file|*.exe";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(ofd.FileName, base64byte);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }

            d.Close();

            //end
            con.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: i replaced it but it seems if(d.Read()) return false _ edit : "reader" is not signed and i replaced it with d.GetString(d.GetOrdinal("fData")); but i have still same problem

Comment: so if there is no data(!) how it can writeAllBytes from database successfully into selected path to save (with my code only. i mean with SaveFileDialog)

Comment: You can't just ensure that the database has the base64 string in the fData column. Can you see the data in database table?

Comment: i sure data will add into table with InsertToDB() function. the reason for why i sure data added to table is : when i restart program at any time(before using CopyFromDB() Function) Datagridview have the data & i can see. but after i use CopyFromDB() funcion & restart program Datagrideview will empty & haven't any data but data have been successfully saved on selected path (exactly like cut and past).

Comment: are you sure its at ID 1, if you used identify and seed it would probably insert the exe at a new row.

Comment: Id status is Primary key and can't be duplicate, see again what's the command to add file : mytbl3TableAdapter.Insert(1, String) , as you can see i use constant. so if we use InsertToDB() function again we will see error : Primary key can't be duplicate

Comment: Since i do not see the whole code - i can't say much further - something else must be removing the entry from db. Are you using DropCreateDatabaseAlways (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.113).aspx) by any chance!

Comment: finally after 1 year i founded the problem! i use "using statement" for all of those commands such as sqlcommand & sqlconnection & .... (when i closed the program without use "using statement"  those commands were still open and they will lose information from my Database) now everything is ok. thanks for your comments.

Comment: No worries, its usually the same case when you use a transaction and make all changes but for get to commit. Glad you found it!